# Is there a NUMSUB command for redis-py?

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

Is there some equivalent to the NUMSUB command in redis for the python client?

I've looked through the documentation and can't find anything other than the publish() method itself, which returns the number of subscribers on that channel. Knowing how many subscribers there are after-the-fact is not very useful to me though.

Comment: Well, it is relating to pubsub stuff, but I mean this numsub method: [link](http://redis.io/commands/pubsub) "pubsub numsub". I want to know how many are subscribed to a specific channel, but I don't see anything like this method on the py-redis stuff.

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be a clean wrapper for these kinds of usecases in redis-py yet, I ended up using a normal redis command to get the subscribers of a specific channel

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(**{
    'host': $WhateverHost,
    'port': 6379,
    })

pubsub = r.pubsub()
pubsub.subscribe('MyChannel:ID')
....
subscriber_count = r.execute_command('PUBSUB', 'NUMSUB', 'MyChannel:ID')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the StrictRedis connection, then create a pubsub object:

```
pubsub(self, shard_hint=None) method of redis.client.StrictRedis instance
    Return a Publish/Subscribe object. With this object, you can
    subscribe to channels and listen for messages that get published to
    them.

rc = redis.StrictRedis()
ps = rc.pubsub()
ps.subscribe(channel)
numsub = ps.subscription_count
```

The pubsub object has methods for subscribing to channels, and a field called subscription_count that give the number of subscribers to the channel.

Comment: @quesadillaswithcheese was this solution working well for you ? subscription_count seems always to be "0"

Comment: It's been a while since I had to use this, but I actually had the same problem once I started testing it out. NUMSUB never quite ended up working out. I don't have the code with me anymore but I ended up using a plain old integer count that I'd increase and decrease as I subscribed/unsubscribed. If anyone else can provide a reason why NUMSUB doesn't seem to change, I would like to know as well! :]